# Is manually freeing resources of JNI method id required

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm learning JNI and I found that jmethodID is actually a pointer.

Do I need to manually free the pointer that is returned by GetMethodID()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the pointer returned from `GetMethodID()` must not be manually freed.

UPDATE:
JNI specification explicitly states when a function allocates something, what must be manually released. If a function does not allocate anything that must be freed then the specification usually does not contain such information explicitly written.

Comment: thanks, is this information in JNI spec? I didn't found it anyway